# What is difference between PropertyOverrideConfigurer and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

What are the differences between using `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in the Spring framework? I'm unable to find any solid difference between these 2 classes.

Comment: this is a perfect question for [search engine of your choice], but completely off-topic for SO.

Comment: Franz Gleichmann why is this off topic ???

Comment: While I don't agree that this is offtopic, he does have a point that googling "PropertyOverrideConfigurer PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" leads to the API docs of `PropertyOverrideConfigurer`, and it contains a paragraph about the difference between those two.

Comment: Thanks @g00glen00b for giving me clues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**PropertyOverrideConfigurer :**

> "Property resource configurer that overrides bean property values in
>   an application context definition. It pushes values from a properties
>   file into bean definitions."

it allows you to override some values that beans take, means you can override some values of spring beans from properties defined in property file

declare:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:myproperties.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="person" class="com.sample.Employee" >
       <property name="name" value="Dugan"/>
       <property name="age" value="50"/>       
</bean>
```

***myproperties.properties:***

```
person.age=40
person.name=Stanis
```

so when you load the bean

```
Employee e  = (Employee)context.getBean(Employee.class);

e.getAge() => 40
e.getName() => "Stanis"
```

**PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** :

> resolves ${...} placeholders against local properties and/or system
>   properties and environment variables.

it allows you to resolve ${..} placeholders in bean definitions, it also checks for System properties for values. This behavior can be controlled with systemPropertiesMode

- never (0): Never check system properties
- fallback (1): Check system properties if not resolvable in the
  specified properties files. This is the default.
- override (2): Check system properties first, before trying the
  specified properties files. This allows system properties to override
  any other property source.

to configure

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

move the 'dataSource' properties to property files

***database.properties***

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password
```

then refer them with place holders =>

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
```